# copy() function doesn't run on laravel running on iis server

Tags: laravel, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a problem sending data over a network share. I have a copy() function running in Controller. The laravel script I have is as follows which is running on the iis server. Example :

```
$src = 'D:\test\tes.txt';
$dst = '\\\\192.168.1.207\SourceIn_\tes.txt';
copy($src, $dst);
```

Here are the results
[image]

And strangely if I use the script using native php it runs without laravel

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what user is running the php script. There is no difference in laravel or pure php in this scenario. The key is in the user who runs it. Your iis is running laravel with a user that has no access permission to that location. Try fix that

Comment: I already setting folder storage for user 'IUSR' full control

Comment: Not IUSR but "IIS APPPOOL\PoolName". Set full control for it.